# How to import a file for processing but not for displaying?

Tags: import, prime-numbers

Here's my problem, I want to take what I have now for code

```
 N[
   Sum[2/10^((n*(Floor[9/n] + 1) - 9)4), {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ 9]]}] + 
   Sum[ 2/(10^((n(Floor[9/n] + 1) - 9)4) (10^(n*4) - 1)), 
     {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ 9]]}] + 
   Sum[2/(10^((o^2 - o - 9)* 4)*(10^(o*4) - 1)), 
     {o, Floor[Sqrt[9]] + 1, 10}], 
   ((10 + 1)^2 - 9)* 4];
AbsoluteTiming[Flatten[
   Position[Partition[RealDigits[%][[1]], 4, 4, -1], {(0) .., 2}]]] + 9
```

and seperate it into two operations. I've read the documentation and it's helped me figure out how to write a file, but I've tried and have not been able to import the file for processeing during the second part without displaying some junk. I've successfully been able to do this,

```
N[
   Sum[2/10^((n*(Floor[9/n] + 1) - 9)4), {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ 9]]}] + 
   Sum[ 2/(10^((n(Floor[9/n] + 1) - 9)4) (10^(n*4) - 1)), 
     {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ 9]]}] + 
   Sum[2/(10^((o^2 - o - 9)* 4)*(10^(o*4) - 1)), 
     {o, Floor[Sqrt[9]] + 1, 10}], 
   ((10 + 1)^2 - 9)* 4] >> "testdd9-10"
```

and I have verified the file using

```
FilePrint["testdd9-10"]
```

but I have been unsucessful with the second part. I've tried,

```
Import["testdd9-10"];
AbsoluteTiming[Flatten[
   Position[Partition[RealDigits[%][[1]], 4, 4, -1], {(0) .., 2}]]] + 9
```

This will be absolutely necessary for me to figure out how to do so that I may process large ranges of primes and sort out formats of numbers which are prime, like safe primes. I have a 6TB hard drive and I'm just itching to fill it.

Comment: `<< "testdd9-10";`, and seeing as you write `testdd9-10` but are trying to import `testdd9-20`, PBCAK...

Comment: @rasher  a typo, I will fix

Comment: no,no the problem is not the typo . the problem is that the  escape character splits the large number into sublists. see my solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy fix:

Export the result in the form `ExpressionML`
Here is the code.

```
 N[
   Sum[2/10^((n*(Floor[9/n] + 1) - 9)4), {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ 9]]}] + 
   Sum[ 2/(10^((n(Floor[9/n] + 1) - 9)4) (10^(n*4) - 1)), 
     {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ 9]]}] + 
   Sum[2/(10^((o^2 - o - 9)* 4)*(10^(o*4) - 1)), 
     {o, Floor[Sqrt[9]] + 1, 10}], 
   ((10 + 1)^2 - 9)* 4] // Export["testdd9-10", #, "ExpressionML"] &
```

Hint: For trouble shooting use

```
Import["testdd9-10"] // InputForm
```

but run your code without `// InputForm` to get a result you can use.

(PS: a 6Tb disk?, I am jealous,hi,hi,hi)

Comment: `Import["testdd9-10"] //ImputForm ` *ImputForm* - is that some new/undocumented feature? ;-)

Comment: I think he means InputForm with an n instead of an m

Comment: Sorry for typo, I have corrected. my fingers are freeeezing...

Comment: @penquin77,This does not yield the intended result. Import["testdd9-10"] // InputForm
   AbsoluteTiming[Flatten[
        Position[Partition[
            RealDigits[%][[1]], 4, 
            4, -1], {(0) .., 
            2}]]] + 9

Comment: @penquin77, Wait a minute, yes it does. BUT, it displays the decimal output afterward, that which I'm hoping to avoid displaying when I begin to deal with larger ranges

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction though

Comment: Sorry for confusion, //InputForm is only for trouble shooting. But take it off to run Input with your code.

Comment: and I should point out that there is another error. I used ((10+1)^2)-9 instead of ((10+1)^2)-1-9. BUT that still doesn't explain why I got 121 and 127 in the final answer. The limit of the range should have been 120. Aw well, just another bug to work out

Comment: @penquin77 Yes! Yes! Yes!   That is it. worked without //InputForm

Comment: please mark question as answered, thanks...:) ... now you can fill your 6TB hi,hi,hi

Comment: @penquin77, No wait, I was getting the decimal output displayed, it's just that it was sumed up in a box for generation of a large input. I don't know if this is going to be a problem or not in the future. Just as long as I don't hit the "Show Full Output" button I should be fine right?

Comment: yes, that's right. Please refer to http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ControllingTheDisplayOfLargeExpressions.html . this might be useful for your project.

Comment: I used a semicolon and got rid of the decimal output